# jquery track changes and add highlight in a input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you check if the value has changed and add a blue highlight? This is for a form element such as a input or checkbox.

```
//highlight the fields that have changed 
var trackChanges = $('[class=input-]')
    .each(function{
    var checkChange = false, 
        //check if data has changed
        if ($(this).data() != $(this).val()) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight')
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: onchange html attribute maybe?

Comment: Well it is hooked up to a database and it saved automatically. I need check what the user enter and compare if the data has changed and if it has changed then the blue highlight will show.

Comment: there 2 answers bellow, none of them works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="inputText">
```

**JAVASCRIPT (Using jQuery):**

```
$("#inputText").change(function(){
    $("#inputText").addClass('highlight');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjuag8mh/1/

[Change Method](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Your answer the was the closest one I needed to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `keydown` event instead that way it will update the color as you type.

```js
$('[class^=input-]').on('keydown', function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 2px solid #3377ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td><input class="input-name" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age: </td>
    <td><input class="input-age" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```